# Percent Sign Inside PHP Variable

Tags: php

I tried to make this condition :

```
if ($Search[1] == '') {
    $Where = 'WHERE User.FirstName LIKE '%$Search[0]%' OR User.LastName LIKE '%$Search[0]%';
}else {
    $Where = 'WHERE User.FirstName LIKE '%$Search[0]%' OR User.LastName LIKE '%$Search[1]%';
}
```

but putting '%$Search[0]%' inside PHP variables cause no result. what is the right way to put percentage sign inside PHP variables?

thanks.

Comment: BTW: note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: how come? those code just a part of codes. can users modify $Where? I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using incorrect quoting

```
$Where = "WHERE User.FirstName LIKE '%$Search[0]%' OR User.LastName LIKE '%$Search[0]%'";
         ^----note the difference.
```

% is the modulo operator in PHP. Since you're using single quotes in your version, you're actually trying to take the modulo of some SQL text and a variable.